# How do I save custom filters in Excel?

Tags: excel, filtering

I have an excel sheet with rows of data that are tagged with one or more words. (example for here: apple, orange, pear-orange, etc)

I know that I can filter for a specific tag, like orange if I put it between asterisks, so that it is found either as a singular value or as part of a more complex tag cell with more tags.

The thing I don't know is how to save these one-tag filters to Excel, so that an average user of the sheet will have to only tick the tag-boxes that they are interested in.

I would appreciate your help with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Simple solution: put a short text above that column explaining how to use "*".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.